# Storing DVDs in a Cooler

Tags: dvd, archiving

I am trying to create the most optimal storage environment for some DVDs in my living space.

I often open my window to maximize airflow, this tends to create significant temperature fluctuations. I am wondering if storing DVDs in a [cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooler) with some dissicant might act as a buffer to these sudden temperature changes and help preserve my DVDs.

I am already familiar with some of [CLIR's recommendations for care and handling](https://www.clir.org/pubs/reports/pub121/pub121.pdf) such as:

> [Do not] Expose discs to extremely rapid temperature or humidity changes.

> A significant, abrupt temperature change will cause greater stress than a gradual change.

*^ The two statements which prompted my question! ^*

> Store discs upright (book style) in plastic cases specified for CDs and DVDs.

> [Do not] Expose recordable discs to prolonged sunlight or other sources of ultraviolet light.

The preservation of the DVDs is not critical; obviously much better results could be obtained with offsite climate controlled storage. My living space is small and is my only viable option for storage.

Comment: What type of DVD's ? Factory pressed or self-written? If the latter: Regular of the shelf writeables or special archive-quality DVD's ?

Comment: They are factory pressed. Maybe my idea of a cooler is a bit overkill... but I like to leave my window open at night, and it can go from warm to cool (very cool) quite fast. Just thought if I threw them in a cooler, maybe that would help offset the temperature change and help preserve the life of the DVDs. I guess it would, but wasn't sure if doing so would introduce some other variable(s) I hadn't considered.

Comment: Why not ripper the DVD to hard drives and forget about the DVD.

Comment: I am looking to preserve the content over a very long course of time. From that perspective, hard drives are actually a worse medium. [Most hard drives last about 5 years](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/170748-how-long-do-hard-drives-actually-live-for). Pressed CDs and DVDs, however, are rumored to last about 20 to 100 years according to NIST. Because these are pressed DVDs I purchased, it is possible I could buy them again in the future. However, with the advent of streaming media, I think much of the current DVD production will cease in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to work for Philips (that invented the CD and later was a main developer of the DVD standard) back in the 90's. We did some reliability studies on CD back then (and later on DVD's).

Based  on what I remember from those:
The main dangers to factory pressed DVD's (and CD's too) are:

- UV light can gradually degrade the plastic they are made of, if the DVD is left in direct sun-light or near a UV light-source (like tanning studio lights). The DVD case (the milky-white or black plastic ones) prevent that from happening. Keeping a DVD in a clear plastic CDROM jewel-case is not such a good idea if you keep it exposed to strong light for longer periods of time.
  It still takes months of exposure before it will become a problem.
- Excess heat makes the plastic malleable which can lead to deformation of the plastic. This takes temperatures of over 80 Celsius. Won't happen in your home unless you have a fire (and then you have bigger problems to worry about).
  This could happen if you leave a DVD laying around in your car when it is parked in full sunlight for a long period of time. Car interiors can get really hot.
- Rapid and frequent temperature changes can cause stresses in the DVD which may cause the reflective layer to de-laminate from the disk itself. I have forgotten the exact figures, but if I remember correctly it takes something like 10 degrees Celsius change (up or down) over 30 minutes applied at least 50 times before it (sometimes) becomes problematic.
  It is possible that recent DVDs (which typically use a Mylar coating in stead of the aluminum on the older disks) are even less sensitive to this.

In short: If you keep them in a cupboard or closed box that insulates them somewhat from the dropping temp in your room they won't cool down fast enough for it to become an issue.
It depends of course a bit on what you consider a "significant temperature fluctuation".
A cooler, as you mentioned, usually has insulated sides which would be even better then just keeping them in a box or cupboard.
You should get at least 50 years out of them. Possibly as much as a 100.

For (re-)writeable CD's/DVD's there is 1 additional aspect: The dyes on these are chemically active which causes a steady (but very slow) degradation over time. Keeping them cool and in the dark keeps that reaction to an absolute minimum and thus extends the usable life. 15-30 years is normally achievable depending on exact composition of the dye.
Archival grade CD/DVD media have special (more expensive) dyes that are less reactive at room-temperature, but you still need to store them dark and cool. These should last for 60 to 100 years if stored properly.
(Of course those shelf-live figures are projections. CD and DVD haven't been around long enough for real experience.)

I still have some CD's I made myself in 1994 that are still in good order. I keep them in a cupboard in my living room at a relatively constant 19 Celsius with no special precautions. (Safety first though: I've got backups of the content "just in case".)